# Is there a name for this pattern? (C# compile-time type-safety with "params" args of different types)

Tags: c#, parameters, type-safety

Is there a name for this pattern?

Let's say you want to create a method that takes a variable number of arguments, each of which must be one of a fixed set of types (in any order or combination), and some of those types you have no control over.  A common approach would be to have your method take arguments of type Object, and validate the types at runtime:

```
void MyMethod (params object[] args)
{
    foreach (object arg in args)
    {
        if (arg is SomeType)
            DoSomethingWith((SomeType) arg);
        else if (arg is SomeOtherType)
            DoSomethingElseWith((SomeOtherType) arg);
        // ... etc.
        else throw new Exception("bogus arg");
    }
}
```

However, let's say that, like me, you're obsessed with compile-time type safety, and want to be able to validate your method's argument types at compile time.  Here's an approach I came up with:

```
void MyMethod (params MyArg[] args)
{
    // ... etc.
}

struct MyArg
{
    public readonly object TheRealArg;

    private MyArg (object obj) { this.TheRealArg = obj; }

    // For each type (represented below by "GoodType") that you want your 
    // method to accept, define an implicit cast operator as follows:

    static public implicit operator MyArg (GoodType x)
    { return new MyArg(x); }

}
```

The implicit casts allow you to pass arguments of valid types directly to your routine, without having to explicitly cast or wrap them.  If you try to pass a value of an unacceptable type, the error will be caught at compile time.

I'm sure others have used this approach, so I'm wondering if there's a name for this pattern.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't see a pattern.

Comment: You know, you could have the "required types" implement a common interface, and then take a `params IWhatever[] args` .

Comment: @Etienne you can't retrofit an interface onto something like a `string`, etc...

Comment: @Marc Yes, but you can always write a wrapper class.

Comment: @Henk In what way do consider it to be over-engineering?  By which I mean, (a) is there another way of achieving compile-time type-safety in the situation I described, or (b) do you consider the goal of compile-time type-safety to be over-engineering in general?

Comment: @Ed I think its over engineering if you have to come up with a solution that unusual because it usually means the way you were originally approaching the problem is faulty.  The simpler solution is to not require a variadic function that uses a type switchboard.

Comment: You know what this reminds me of? PHP. Even though PHP is dynamically-typed while C# is statically-typed.

Comment: I was skeptical at first, but I think this is actually kinda useful. And I've not seen this pattern/antipattern used before. Ever.

Comment: @Etienne: That "wrapper class" you suggest is exactly what Ed implemented with `MyArg`!

Comment: You've added an implicit cast method to your code for every type in myMethod's capabilities.  You've added a Wrapper class and for each argument type you deem good, you'll have a constructor for MyArg.  If you ever want to be able to handle an additional type in MyMethod you must make updates to two locations rather than the one.  Looks like you've added responsibility to the programmer to not break your code, instead of making it easier.

Comment: @Ryan: How would you implement a function like `printf` or `ExecuteSql` without requiring a variadic function that uses a type switchboard?

Comment: @Ed - This is an excellent question, and a well thought out solution, even if my answer seems to indicate otherwise

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be a named pattern on the Interwebs, but based on [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/864087/ryan-russell)'s comment to your question, I vote the name of the pattern should be **[Variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) Typesafety**.

Generally, I would use it very sparingly, but I'm not judging the pattern as good or bad. Many of the commenters have made good points pro and con, which we see for other patterns such as *Factory*, *Service Locator*, *Dependency Injection*, *MVVM*, etc. It's all about context. So here's a stab at that...

**Context**

A variable set of disparate objects must be processed.

**Use When**

1. Your method can accept a variable number of arguments of disparate types that don't have a common base type.
2. Your method is widely used (i.e. in many places in code and/or by a great number of users of your framework. The point being that the type-safety provides enough of a benefit to warrant its use.
3. The arguments can be passed in any order, yet the set of disparate types is finite and the only set acceptable to the method.
4. Expressiveness is your design goal and you don't want to put the onus on the user to create wrappers or adapters (see *Alternatives*).

**Implementation**

*You already provided that.*

**Examples**

- LINQ to XML (e.g. `new XElement(...)`)
- Other builders such as those that build SQL parameters.
- Processor facades (e.g. those that could accept different types of delegates or command objects from different frameworks) to execute the commands without the need to create explicit command adapters.

**Alternatives**

- *Adapter*. Accept a variable number of arguments of some adapter type (e.g. `Adapter<T>` or subclasses of a non-generic `Adapter`) that the method can work with to produce the desired results. This widens the set your method can use (the types are no-longer finite), but nothing is lost if the adapter does the right thing to enable the processing to still work. The disadvantage is the user has the additional burden of specifying existing and/or creating new adapters, which perhaps detracts from the intent (i.e. adds "ceremony", and weakens "essence").
- *Remove Type Safety*. This entails accepting a very base type (e.g. `Object`) and placing runtime checks. Burden on what to know to pass is passed to the user, but the code is still expressive. Errors don't reveal themselves until runtime.
- *Composite*. Pass a single object that is a composite of others. This requires a pre-method-call build up, but devolves back to using one of the above patterns for the items in the composite's collection.
- *Fluent API*. Replace the single call with a series of specific calls, one for each type of acceptable argument. A canonical example is `StringBuilder`.

Comment: StringBuilder ...good example. I would be in favor of overloaded methods. You mentioned *Expressiveness* - made me wonder about the possibility of a custom derivation of `Expression`. Maybe a ParameterTree ...kind of an 'off the cuff' idea.

Answer (score 1):

It is called an anti-pattern more commonly known as [Poltergeist](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PolterGeists).

Update:

If the types of args are always constant and the order does not matter, then create overloads that each take collections (IEnumerable<T>) changing T in each method for the type you need to operate on. This will reduce your code complexity by:

1. Removing the MyArg class
2. eliminating the need for type casting in your MyMethod
3. will add an additional compile time type safety in that if you try to call the method with a list of args that you can't handle, you will get a compiler exception.

Comment: I disagree, this could potentially be useful in a library. Type-safety ftw.

Comment: this constructor "private MyArg (object obj) { this.TheRealArg = obj; }" removes any possibility of compile time type safety. Also the casts in MyMethod eliminate the compile time type safety that the methods DoSomethingWith and DoSomethingElseWith get for free.

Comment: Eh, and what if they are not constant? I want to call my function like so: `f(10, "hello", new Exception("bugger it"))`, and I only want it to accept those types. Only valid argument against this is saying that you never need to do that. I suggest it might be useful when providing library call methods, and I'm playing with it now, and I think it's kind of neat.

Comment: @Charles: The constructor you're concerned about is `private` so it can only be called by the approved implicit cast operators.

Comment: @Gabe - missed that one. removed the type safety info from my answer

Comment: While I agree that you are correct in the event that the arg types don't get mixed within a single call, I think we can assume that arg types *will* be mixed for the purposes of naming this pattern. Consider implementing a `printf` or `ExecuteSql` function where you know ahead of time which types you can accept (`int`, `bool`, `float`, `string`, `DateTime`) but not how many of them there will be nor in what combination.

Comment: @Gabe - Your examples imply a specific order, his example explicitly states that order of application is not important. If order was important, then the compile-time type safety would not work here. You could still swap out two incompatible but valid types by specifying them in the wrong order. And this would produce a type cast exception at runtime, which is the exact thing this pattern is trying to avoid. (on an aside, F#'s printf can enforce compile time type safety by examining the placeholders in the format string and comparing them against the type supplied)

Comment: @Charles: Given that `ExecuteSql` can't validate that its parameters are of the correct types (only the DB can do that), are you suggesting that you might as well give up on type-safety all together? I don't see the argument for accepting types that are known at compile-time to not be valid.

Comment: @Gabe - Not at all, I'm saying that when parameter order matters this pattern does not solve the problem for which it was designed. I personally would not have any more confidence in the lack of run time errors using object, instead of MyArgs, when I know that there can still be type cast errors at run time. Since, object is just there, you don't need to implement anything extra, so there is less code to maintain. So, when parameter order matters, I would recommend just using object. When it doesn't, as the question states, I have provided a solution in addition to my answer about the pattern.

Comment: @Charles: The hypothetical `ExecuteSql` function doesn't throw type cast errors if `MyArgs` is used. If you pass a `bool` where a `string` is expected, you may get a `SqlException`, the DB may convert the `bool` for you, or exception handling in the DB will take care of it. I don't see why it's better to generate errors at run time that can be caught at compile time just because not all errors can be caught at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a **subset** of the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). Quoting from Wikipedia:

The composite pattern describes that a group of objects are to be treated in the same way as a single instance of an object.

Comment: Possibly, it's the closest GoF pattern I know that fits the case.