# C#: type safety over sets of integers (e. g. enums)

Tags: c#, enums, type-safety

I have a case where I have several sets of numbers (register values). I want to improve readability and also to check appropriate types (only certain values make sense in certain functions).

In my particular implementation, I made them enums - so I have a set of enums now.

Now I seem to have reached the end on this approach, since I want to divide them into sets of valid enums for certain applications - so function A could for example take (a value from) enumA, enumB and enumC as input, but not enumD which is a description of different functionality.

I already looked into enums in interfaces and enum inheritance - both are dead ends, not possible in C#.

I wonder now how the solution to this problem might look like. I would like to get intellisense on the possible values and also have some type safety, so that I could not (well, at least not without maliciously casting it) feed the wrong values in.

How to achieve this?

(Possible solutions would be to simply write several functions taking several different enums - still possible but not really nice, or something like [Is there a name for this pattern? (C# compile-time type-safety with "params" args of different types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927642/is-there-a-name-for-this-pattern-c-compile-time-type-safety-with-params-arg) - both just seems not too nice.)

Comment: Although extension of Enum's that requires access to internals is not possible in C#, it IS possible to implement many extenstions to num's using extension methods. Are you aware of how to create an extension method?

Comment: You mean extension method to my integer, so I could write 2.MyMethod()? If I understand you correctly, I do not know how that could help me. How would I get either type-safety or even some ordering as an enum provides?

Comment: No, extension methods to your Enums to extend them. You stated that extending the Enums was a dead end, but it really isn't. Since Enum's have no internals, Extension methods are quite adequate here.

Comment: ANd if you actually need Enums with internals, then they chould be classes/objects instead of Enums, as suggested in one of the answers below.

Comment: You are talking about extension methods? Since I said that a) inheritance and b) interfaces are a dead end to me.

Comment: @AndreasReiff: Your question just like another question just asked [Delimiter Replacement Approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254120/delimiter-replacement-approach), so the applicable answer is [Servy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254047/c-type-safety-over-sets-of-integers-e-g-enums/15254430#15254430).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to scrap enums and use your own clases designed to mimic enums.  It will be a bit more work for you to set them up, but once you do it will be easy enough to use, and will be able to have the functionality you've described.

```
public class Register
{
    private int value;

    internal Register(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static readonly Register NonSpecialRegister = new Register(0);
    public static readonly Register OtherNonSpecialRegister = new Register(1);

    public static readonly SpecialRegister SpecialRegister 
        = SpecialRegister.SpecialRegister;
    public static readonly SpecialRegister OtherSpecialRegister 
        = SpecialRegister.OtherSpecialRegister;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return value.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Register other = obj as Register;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        return other.value == value;
    }
}

public class SpecialRegister : Register
{
    internal SpecialRegister(int value) : base(value) { }

    public static readonly SpecialRegister SpecialRegister = new SpecialRegister(2);
    public static readonly SpecialRegister OtherSpecialRegister = new SpecialRegister(3);
}
```

Given this, you could have a method like:

```
public static void Foo(Register reg)
{
}
```

That could take any register, and could be called like:

```
Foo(Register.NonSpecialRegister);
Foo(Register.OtherSpecialRegister);
```

Then you could have another method such as:

```
public static void Bar(SpecialRegister reg)
{
}
```

Which wouldn't be able to accept a `Register.NonSpecialRegister`, but could accept a `Register.OtherSpecialRegister` or `SpecialRegister.SpecialRegister`.

Comment: It looks like it could work - though I would need 1 additional level of inheritance, clustering SpecialRegister1 and SpecialRegister2 as allowed SpecialRegister-sets. And yes, a lot of writing needed. :)

Comment: @AndreasReiff I assumed from the code provided that you could extrapolate to any number of sub-types with any level of depth; adding more is tedious and a fair bit of typing, but not intellectually hard.

Comment: @AndreasReiff: It is exact the way to do.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have exhausted the capabilities of the static type system on the CLR. You can still get runtime validation by wrapping each integer with a class that validates that the value you try to store in it actually is a member of the static set.

If you have a reliable test suite or are willing to do manual testing this will at least catch the bugs instead of the bugs causing silent data corruption.

If you have multiple "sets" that you want to keep apart you can either use class inheritance or have a set of user-defined conversion operators which validate that the conversion is OK at runtime.

I don't know what specific requirements you have but maybe you can use class-based inheritance to check some properties statically. The base class would be the larger set in that case and derived classes would specialize the set of allowed values.

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two options:

#### Option 1: Multiple enums

Create multiple enums, one for each application, and replicate the values in each enum. Then you can cast between them. For example:

```
enum App1
{
    Data1 = AppAll.Data1,
    Data2 = AppAll.Data2,
    Data42 = AppAll.Data42,
}

enum App2
{
    Data2 = AppAll.Data2,
    Data16 = AppAll.Data16,
    Data42 = AppAll.Data42,
}

enum AppAll
{
    Data1 = 1,
    Data2 = 2,
    Data16 = 16,
    Data42 = 42,
}

App1 value1 = (App1)AppAll.Data2;
App2 value2 = (App2)value1;
```

This will give you IntelliSense.

#### Option 2: Determine which are allowed

Create a method that returns a boolean on which values are allowed (this may be virtual and overridden for each application). Then you can throw an exception when the enum value is wrong.

```
public bool IsAllowed(AppAll value)
{
    return value == AppAll.Data2
        || value == AppAll.Data16
        || value == AppAll.Data42;
}


if (!IsAllowed(value))
    throw new ArgumentException("Enum value not allowed.");
```

This will not give you IntelliSense.

---

A few notes:

- You cannot have inheritance for enums because under the covers enums are represented as `structs` (i.e. value types).
- In C# you can literally cast *any* value to your enum type, even when it is not a member of it. For example, I can do `(App1)1337` even when there is no member with value `1337`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want *compile* type checking, you are better off with distinct enums for distinct  cases. If you want to have a master enum with all of your possibilities you can write a test that ensures that all of your "child" enum lists are valid subsets of the master (in terms of Int casts).

As an alternative, I would have to wonder (since no code is provided, I can only wonder) if you might not be better served with objects with methods for each enum option. Then you inherit out objects with the various methods instead of enums. (After all, it seems that you are using Enums as proxies for method signatures).

Comment: It is not so much checking for valid values that is important for me. It is more making sure that I cannot accidentally use a "wrong" set of values at the wrong place, since that is going to lead to bad readability later. Also most enums have the same values (they are register sets, or actually offsets, where some sets perform similar). So main concern really is readability, that is why I mentioned type-safety and the ability to "cluster" them.

Comment: It sounds (again, we have little to work with here, being secretive is a challenge for people trying to help) like you perhaps have a problem that might be better served with a domain specific language or other higher level construct. Our commission system is data driven rather than code driven so we can run our complex rules (underwriter, carrier, wholesaler, retail and state by state legal rules) making the code very simple and ensuring readability by using editor pages that enforce all the constraints.

Comment: Well.. being secretive certainly is not what I want to do. So.. I have a set of sets of numbers. They actually map to registers on hardware. Certain registers in different sets still can be accessed the same way, others cannot. So, for that functionality, I want to make sure I have to appropriate input from one of the sets of registers that is appropriate. (In the end, all are numbers, but they have different meaning - that is why I talk about type-safety and grouping.)

Comment: So, for the sake of argument, let's say we are talking about an ARM processor with R0-R15. These registers are accessed by different op-codes in different ways, so what you need is a mapping of opcode/register use rules?

Comment: In my hardware I have several clusters of registers. For example, I have a set of Motor registers and a set of Light registers. I want to talk to both (different) sets through the function writeRegisterOnARM. I have different sets of registers Airconditioning and Radio that I want accessible through writeRegisterOnAtmel. So Motor (0..8) and Light (0..5) are different but can still be used for the same function writeRegisterOnARM - unlike Airconditioning (0..8).

Comment: I'm going to back @Servy's suggestion (I have upvoted it) if you want to keep everything within the compiler itself. Otherwise I would recommend looking at a small Domain Specific Language where you could encode your operator/register rules and provide direct support for your hardware.