# Delimiter Replacement Approach

Tags: c#, asp.net

I’d like to create a method to replace delimiters for the intended target use (html email, log, database). The delimiters are constant so I’d like to be able to reference a object that maps recognizable names to string values (semicolon = “;”, htmlLineBreak = “<br/>”, etc.). Is there a better means to do this than this below?

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public string ReplaceDelimiter(string content
                     , Delimiter currentDelimiter, Delimiter outputDelimiter)
    {
        return content.Replace(currentDelimiter.ToString()
                              , outputDelimiter.ToString());
    }
}

public class Delimiter
{
    public const string comma = ",";
    public const string semicolon = ";";
    public const string colon = ":";
    public const string lineBreak = "\r\n";
    public const string htmlLineBreak = "<br/>";
}
```

**Edited following comments:**
A use case would be when I want to log an error to different targets and send the same contents (formatted differently) in an email. The log may go to a database column (want key/value with semicolon delimiter) or log file (want delimiter to be line breaks). The email would be HTML so want the delimiter to be replaced with <br/>.

Below would be an excerpt from a logging method that has a few parameters including the actual Exception:

```
StringBuilder delimitedMessage = new StringBuilder();

delimitedMessage.Append("Date=" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ";");
delimitedMessage.Append("Time=" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ";");
delimitedMessage.Append("Source=" + objException.Source.ToString().Trim() + ";");
delimitedMessage.Append("Method=" + objException.TargetSite.Name.ToString() + ";");
delimitedMessage.Append("Erring Method=" + methodName + ";");
delimitedMessage.Append("Computer=" + System.Environment.MachineName.ToString() + ";");
delimitedMessage.Append("Log Message=" + logMessage + ";");
delimitedMessage.Append("Exception Error=" + objException.Message.ToString().Trim() + ";");
delimitedMessage.Append("Severity=" + severity.ToString() + ";");
delimitedMessage.Append("Stack Trace=" + objException.StackTrace.ToString().Trim() + ";");

contentToLog = delimitedMessage.ToString();

WriteToDb(contentToLog);
WriteToLog(Utilities.ReplaceDelimiter(contentToLog, Delimiter.semicolon, Delimiter.lineBreak));
SendEmail(Utilities.ReplaceDelimiter(contentToLog, Delimiter.semicolon, Delimiter.htmlLineBreak));
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: Why are you passing about a static class? They'll both be 'current' or 'output' - there's no difference. Other than that, you could consider a dictionary, to iterate keys and replace by value, but it's not clear how this could be made better _for you_.

Comment: Do you want something which can cope with "a,b,c","d" or maybe a\,b\,c,d? If not, what you have is fine.

Comment: Use Environment.NewLine instead of \r\n

Comment: @BradM Unless he's using it for HTTP headers or similar, which require \r\n. It depends on what he wants to do with it.

Comment: I would think that you want to keep the data in a class of some kind, then serialize it to the different formats. Stop thinking in terms of "delimiters".

Answer (score 1):

- Code

  ```
  public class Delimiter {
      public static readonly Delimiter
          HtmlLineBreak=new Delimiter {
              Value="<br/>"
          },
          LineBreak=new Delimiter {
              Value="\r\n"
          },
          Semicolon=new Delimiter {
              Value=";"
          },
          Colon=new Delimiter {
              Value=":"
          },
          Comma=new Delimiter {
              Value=","
          };

      public override String ToString() {
          return Value;
      }

      public String Value {
          get;
          set;
      }
  }
  ```
- Test

  ```
  var t=Utilities.ReplaceDelimiter("123\r\n", Delimiter.LineBreak, Delimiter.HtmlLineBreak);
  Debug.Print("{0}", t);
  ```
- Output

  > 123<br/>